# Can I change the magento logging timestamps offset?

Tags: magento

Is there a way to change the `Mage::log()` timestamp in magento? I would prefer it to match my timezone.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. Have you looked at the source?

Comment: I know it all extends from the Zend_Log::log() method, which has a hard-coded date('c') for the timestamp placeholder in the format.  but I'm not sure if there is a way to adjust this...I don't think so.

Comment: If you have access to the source code, you can modify anything you'd like, can't you?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73390/) which might be some help.

> Magento internally sets all cron dates to occur in GMT, it actually overrides the server php time zone settings so that all log events and all cron time schedules are triggered in the GMT timezone - you can see this in Mage.php on line 527. All php time functions called within Magento will be in GMT as a result (like the timestamp in the log call above).
>
> Magento then adds back your timezone offset based on your locale settings when it shows you times in the admin panel.
> It does this so you can run multiple stores in different timezones based on your locale choice and ideally you would never know nor care about this - but it makes debugging cron events really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

change 
/lib/Zend/Log.php:345

```
protected function _packEvent($message, $priority)
{
    return array_merge(array(
        'timestamp'    => date($this->_timestampFormat),
        'message'      => $message,
        'priority'     => $priority,
        'priorityName' => $this->_priorities[$priority]
        ),
        $this->_extras
    );
}
```

to

```
protected function _packEvent($message, $priority)
{
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );

    return array_merge(array(
        'timestamp'    => $date->format($this->_timestampFormat),
        'message'      => $message,
        'priority'     => $priority,
        'priorityName' => $this->_priorities[$priority]
        ),
        $this->_extras
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I am from India, in `app/mage.php` at around line number 767, I modified this to be:

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

Then it started displaying my local time as time stamp in log files. So you can add your own time zone...I'm sure it will work.

Comment: This is poor advice. You have no idea what other effects this will have on anything that expects the timezone to be UTC. Plus updating Magento will overwrite the change, one main reason for not changing core files.